# Laravel project wont serve to given ip via Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am having trouble setting up my laravel project on my mac. I have (As far as I can tell) set up the homestead.yaml config correctly within my Homestead directory:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/GitHub/project-darwin
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
      php: "7.2"

databases:
    - homestead
```

After I have used `vagrant up`, on using `vagrant ssh` I can see my project inside of `vagrant/code/project-darwin`.

My hosts file is as follows:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

192.168.10.10   homestead.test
```

Which looks correct as is no different to what I normally do when running other laravel projects on virtualbox, however on going to my url, I get a 500 error and the same applies if I go directly to the ip (198.168.10.10).

A further thing I find suspicious is the following. When I use `vagrant up`, this is part of what shows in my terminal:

```
homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
```

Should this ip be the same as the ip I supplied? Anyway, I have run out of ideas as to how to go about fixing this, any suggestions?

Comment: I might not have the answer to your question but you can solve it in another way. every Laravel project comes with a built-in server for easy development. in your Laravel project open terminal and run `php artisan serve`. now you can have response on `port 8000` (default port that you can change) on your browser or postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my mac had auto selected . hyperv as my provider when I ran `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`, oh well..

Answer (score 0):

In your Homestead.yaml config file you are doing the following:

Making a shared folder mapping project-darwin to /home/vagrant/code

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/GitHub/project-darwin
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

But under sites you are mapping the folder /home/vagrant/code/public to homestead.test, meaning when you are requesting homestead.test or the IP of your Vagrant Box, you are not calling upon project-darwin but rather the "empty" public folder.

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
```

I would recommend either moving your code to the public folder or mapping sites to your desired destination.

Hope this helps :)